Hindu mythology. We already know that Kalki Avatar will appear in Kaliyuga. So was it already known in Tretayuga that Krishna will come in Dwaparyuga
We already know that Kalki Avatar will appear in Kaliyuga before his appearance. So was it already known in Tretayuga that Lord Krishna will come in Dwaparyuga, like is it written in the sacred texts which are said to exist before the Time of Lord Krishna?

All avatars of Lord are mentioned in various Puranas. There are nearly 22 avatars mentioned, some which are before Matysa avatar of Lord Vishnu (Dashavatara).
Garuda Purana mentions all of them in the starting chapter.
Purana are taken from Vedas which date back to pre-historic times.
Buddha avatar (500 BC) is also mentioned in Purana which is dated 1500 B.C (oral).
Ref: 

Origin, Development and General Survey of Puranas

